# Threads are going wild in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I am a newbie when it comes to multitheadinG so here we go.. I have this task where i get to multiply 2 matrices in 2 ways: in parallel and in a thread pool. Moreover, i have to use this subtask where i compute each element of the resulting matrix that i need to use.

What ever I do, my threads run completely randomly meaning that some values double their value over and voer again. I will attach some outputs in order to see.

Thisi is my messy code:

Class Matrix:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Matrix {

    private List<List<Integer>> matrix;
    Random random = new Random();

    private int rows;
    private int cols;

    public Matrix(int row, int col)
    {
        this.rows = row;
        this.cols = col;

        makeRandomMatrix(rows, cols);
    }

    public List<Integer> getRow(int index)
    {
        return this.matrix.get(index);
    }

    public List<Integer> getCol(int index)
    {
        List<Integer> col = new ArrayList<>();

        for (List<Integer> row: this.matrix){
            col.add(row.get(index));
        }
        return col;
    }

    public void setRow(int rowNo, List<Integer> row) throws Exception {
        if (row.size() != this.cols){
            throw new Exception("Cannot add row of length " + String.valueOf(row.size()) + " to a " + "(" + String.valueOf(this.rows) + ", " + String.valueOf(this.cols) + ") matrix");
        }
        this.matrix.set(rowNo, row);
    }

    public void setCol(int colNo, List<Integer> col) throws Exception {
        if (col.size() != this.rows){
            throw new Exception("Cannot add col of length " + String.valueOf(col.size()) + " to a " + "(" + String.valueOf(this.rows) + ", " + String.valueOf(this.cols) + ") matrix");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < col.size(); i++){
            this.matrix.get(i).set(colNo, col.get(i));
        }
    }

    public int get(int row, int col){
        return this.matrix.get(row).get(col);
    }

    public void set(int row, int col, int value){
        this.matrix.get(row).set(col, value);
    }

    public int getRowsNumber() {
        return rows;
    }

    public int getColsNumber() {
        return cols;
    }

    public int index(int row, int col){
        return row * this.cols + col;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++){
            ss.append(this.matrix.get(i).toString()).append("\n");
        }

        return ss.toString();
    }

    public void makeRandomMatrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        this.matrix = new ArrayList<>(rows);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++)
        {
            this.matrix.add(new ArrayList<>(cols));
            for (int j = 0; j < this.cols; j++)
            {
                this.matrix.get(i).add(random.nextInt(10));
            }
        }
    }

    public void makeEmptyMatrix(int rows, int cols)
    {

        this.matrix = new ArrayList<>(rows);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++)
        {
            this.matrix.add(new ArrayList<>(cols));
            for (int j = 0; j < this.cols; j++)
            {
                this.matrix.get(i).add(0);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Class MatrixOperation:

```
import com.sun.source.tree.MemberReferenceTree;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class MatrixOperations {

    private Matrix a;
    private Matrix b;
    private ReentrantLock lock;

    public MatrixOperations(Matrix aa, Matrix bb)
    {
        this.a = aa;
        this.b = bb;
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    public Matrix getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public Matrix getB() {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MatrixOperations{" +
                "a=" + a +
                ", b=" + b +
                '}';
    }

    public void multiply(Matrix a, Matrix b) {
        assert a.getRowsNumber() == b.getColsNumber();
        Matrix result = new Matrix(a.getRowsNumber(), b.getColsNumber());
        for (int i = 0; i < a.getRowsNumber(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.getColsNumber(); j++) {
                result.set(i, j, 0);
                for (int k = 0; k < result.getRowsNumber(); k++) {
                    result.set(i, j, result.get(i, j) + a.get(i, k) * b.get(k, j));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(result);
    }

    public void subTaskMultiply(Matrix a, Matrix b, Matrix result, int rowIndexA, int rowIndexB)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<a.getColsNumber();i++)
        {
            result.set(rowIndexA, rowIndexB, result.get(rowIndexA, rowIndexB) + a.get(rowIndexA, i) * b.get(i, rowIndexB));
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }


    public synchronized void  multiplyParallel(Matrix a, Matrix b, int threadCount) throws InterruptedException {
        Matrix result = new Matrix(a.getRowsNumber(), b.getColsNumber());
        result.makeEmptyMatrix(a.getRowsNumber(), b.getColsNumber());
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<threadCount;i++)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start.");
                    result.makeEmptyMatrix(a.getRowsNumber(), b.getColsNumber());
                    for(int i=0;i<a.getRowsNumber();i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=0;j<b.getColsNumber();j++)
                        {
                            subTaskMultiply(a,b,result, i,j);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End.");

                }
            });

            thread.start();
            threads.add(thread);
        }

        for(Thread threadd : threads)
        {
            try{
                threadd.join();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        threads.clear();
    }

    public void multiplyThreadPool(Matrix a, Matrix b)
    {
        Matrix result = new Matrix(a.getRowsNumber(), b.getColsNumber());
        result.makeEmptyMatrix(a.getRowsNumber(), b.getColsNumber());
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            Runnable worker = new MultiplyWorkerThread(a,b, result, a.getRowsNumber(), b.getColsNumber(), this);
            executorService.execute(worker);
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        while(!executorService.isTerminated())
        {
        }
        System.out.println("Finished with all threads");
    }
}
```

Class MatrixWorkerThread - used for the thread pool

```
public class MultiplyWorkerThread extends Thread implements Runnable {

    private Matrix a;
    private Matrix b;
    private Matrix result;
    private int indexA;
    private int indexB;
    private MatrixOperations op;

    public MultiplyWorkerThread(Matrix aa, Matrix bb, Matrix result, int indexa, int indexb, MatrixOperations opp)
    {
        this.a = aa;
        this.b = bb;
        this.result = result;
        this.indexA = indexa;
        this.indexB = indexb;
        this.op = opp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start.");
        result.makeEmptyMatrix(a.getRowsNumber(), b.getColsNumber());
        for(int i=0;i<indexA;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<indexB;j++)
            {
                op.subTaskMultiply(a,b,result, i,j);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End.");

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MultiplyWorkerThread{" +
                "a=" + a +
                ", b=" + b +
                ", op=" + op +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Main:

```
import java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Matrix a = new Matrix(2,2);
        a.makeRandomMatrix(2,2);
        Matrix b = new Matrix(2,2);
        b.makeRandomMatrix(2,2);

        MatrixOperations op = new MatrixOperations(a,b);

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);

        System.out.println("SIMPLE MULTIPLY");
        op.multiply(a,b);

        System.out.println("THREAD POOL MULTIPLY: ");
        op.multiplyParallel(a,b,12);

        



    }
}
```

So this is what I have so far

Comment: You have 10 threads, all running simultaneously. The first thing they all do, all more or less simultaneously, is invoke `makeEmptyMatrix`, __on the same matrix object__, and will then all simultaneously call `.set` on the same matrix a bunch. That's... what parallel means. I'm confused as to why you're confused. Maybe explain what you expected to happen and in your words what you think should happen when using multiple threads, because the problem appears to be in your understanding of these concepts.

Comment: thanks for your response. the aim of this was to have a function that computes a single element of the resulting matrix and to use that function in order to multiply 2 matrices conccurently. I tried to to that with simple threads and with a thread pool but seems that i failed in both ways -_-

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you synchronize your code. Usually you synchronize data structures to prevent concurrent manipulation so that multiple threads can safely manipulate them. If one thread is in a synchronized method all other threads can't enter this block.
You might want to split the problem into chunks e.g. a part of the matrix. Think about input and output of the function.
For example split the big matrix into several small ones you want to multiply and build a queue of tasks to execute. Each task with input (m1, m2) and output (r). After processing all tasks you can assemble the result matrix.
If you use a Collections.synchronizedCollection() each thread you start can fetch the next task from the list, process it and put the result into the result list, until the task list is empty. After the task list is empty and you have all results you can assemble the result.
This describes the idea. Try to process the list with one thread and than start multiple. If you got this up and running you might want to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong with your code.  The biggest issue is here is that your threads are modifying the shared result `Matrix` without any data synchronization.   Any time 2 threads modify the same object, you need to figure out how you are protecting it against data and logic race conditions.  Threads get their speed because they utilize memory caching on the CPU they are running on.  Each thread would update it's *copy* of the result in its own CPU cache and how the changes to the cached copy make it to main memory is not defined by your program.  I bet you see different results each time you run your program because of this.

You could certainly mark every method in `Matrix` as `synchronized` but this would cause a *lot* of data contention and would slow down your program.  If the threads are working on different portions of the matrix, I would recommend that each thread modify it's own `Matrix` and then merge those matrixes at the end after the threads have finished.

Also:

- Your `MultiplyWorkerThread` class should implement `Runnable` but *not* extend `Thread`.  The thread pool creates threads for you.  It should be renamed to `MultiplyWorkerTask` or something.
- The `synchronized` keyword on the `multiplyParallel(...)` method does nothing because there aren't multiple threads calling that method at the same time.  In case there was a question, just because you use that keyword doesn't protect the shared `result` matrix created inside the method.
- You are spinning in your `while(!executorService.isTerminated())` which is very expensive.  Either put a `Thread.sleep(...)` in the loop or better would be to use the `ExecutorService.awaitTermination(...)`.
- Seems like your matrix would be a lot more efficient if it used arrays instead of lists.